# How to fit ARSCNView to SafeArea on iPhone X?

Tags: ios, storyboard, augmented-reality, arkit

How can I fit an ARSCNView Object to fit on SafeArea for iPhone X with storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select ARSCNView's top constraint (`Scene View.top = top`) and then in **Size Inspector** change a property called `Second Item` from **Superview** to **Safe Area**.

[image]

Now in Document Outline area it reads: `Scene View.top = Safe Area.top`.

`Constant = 0` This property is an offset.

[image]

Then choose `View as: iPhone Xs` at the bottom of Xcode:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: no, it didn't size the view to the edges at the notch and at the bottom

Comment: Use `Constant` property for necessary offset.